# RSS function results in syntax error for certain property

Tags: php, mysql, html, rss

I have a function to build a rss feed with PHP:

```
function createRSS() {
    $currentDate = time();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ". ADS_TABLE ." WHERE expires > $currentDate ORDER BY enterd DESC LIMIT 0,400";
    $results = myExec($sql);
    // open a file pointer to an RSS file
    $fp = fopen ("mexautosrss.xml", "w");
    if (!$fp) {
    // Can't write to a file
    return;
    }

    fwrite ($fp, "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1' ?>\n");
    //ERROR:  fwrite ($fp, "<rss version='2.0' xmlns:atom="http://www.mexautos.com/mexautosrss.xml"><channel>\n");
    fwrite ($fp, "<title>MexAutos.com</title>\n");
    //ERROR:  fwrite ($fp, "<atom:link href="http://www.mexautos.com/mexautosrss.xml" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />\n");
    fwrite ($fp, "<link>http://www.mexautos.com/</link>\n");
    fwrite ($fp, "<description>Anuncios de Autos y Camionetas Usados en Mexico.</description>\n");
    fwrite ($fp, "<language>es-mx</language>\n");
    fwrite ($fp, "<docs>http://www.mexautos.com/mexautosrss.xml</docs>\n");
    fwrite ($fp, "<image>\n");
    fwrite ($fp, " <title>Mexautos.com</title>\n");
    fwrite ($fp, " <url>http://www.mexautos.com/images/logo_top_es.gif</url>\n");
    fwrite ($fp, " <link>http://www.mexautos.com</link>\n");
    fwrite ($fp, "</image>\n");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
        $makeId = $row['make'];
        $makeSQL = "SELECT name FROM ". CAR_MAKES_TABLE ." WHERE pkMakeID=$makeId";
        $makeResults = myExec($makeSQL);
        $make = mysql_fetch_row($makeResults);
        $modelId = $row['model'];
        $makeSQL = "SELECT name FROM ". CAR_MODELS_TABLE ." WHERE pkModelID=$modelId";
        $makeResults = myExec($makeSQL);
        $model = mysql_fetch_row($makeResults);
        $stateId = $row['state'];
        $makeSQL = "SELECT name FROM ". STATES_TABLE ." WHERE pkStateID=$stateId";
        $makeResults = myExec($makeSQL);
        $state = mysql_fetch_row($makeResults);
        $title = $make[0]." ".$row['make_other']." ".$model[0]." ".$row['model_other']." '".$row['model_year'];
        $content = "$".$row['price']." mil pesos ".$row['color']." Clima: ".$row['clima']." ".$row['milage']." mil kms Puertas: ".$row['doors']." ".$row['transmission']." ".$row['comment']." Tel: ".$row['tel_num']." (".$state[0].")";
        $search = array(
            '@<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>@si', // Strip out javascript
            '@<[\/\!]*?[^<>]*?>@si', // Strip out HTML tags
            '@([\r\n])[\s]+@', // Strip out white space
            '@&(quot|#34);@i', // Replace HTML entities
            '@&(amp|#38);@i',
            '@&(lt|#60);@i',
            '@&(gt|#62);@i',
            '@&(nbsp|#160);@i',
            '@&(iexcl|#161);@i',
            '@&(cent|#162);@i',
            '@&(pound|#163);@i',
            '@&(copy|#169);@i',
            '@&(acento|#0027);@i',
            '@&#(\d+);@e'
        ); // evaluate as php
        $replace = array(
            '',
            '',
            '\1',
            '"',
            '&',
            '<',
            '>',
            ' ',
            'chr(161)',
            'chr(162)',
            'chr(163)',
            'chr(169)',
            'chr(\1)'
        );
        $content = preg_replace($search, $replace, $content);
        $title = preg_replace("/&/", 'y', $title);
        $content = preg_replace("/&/", 'y', $content);
        fwrite ($fp, "<item>\n");
        fwrite ($fp, " <title>$title</title>\n");
        fwrite ($fp, " <description>$content</description>\n");
        fwrite ($fp, " <link>http://www.mexautos.com/</link>\n");
        fwrite ($fp, "<guid>http://www.mexautos.com</guid>\n");
        fwrite ($fp, "</item>\n");
    }
    fwrite ($fp, "</channel></rss>\n");
    fclose ($fp);
}
```

The problem is that I get an error if I do not comment out the `atom:link` lines, it shows:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING
```

Could someone point me where its the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you contain double-quote characters inside a double-quoted string in PHP (or just about any other language), you need to escape those literal double-quote characters.

```
fwrite ($fp, "<rss version='2.0' xmlns:atom=\"http://www.mexautos.com/mexautosrss.xml\"><channel>\n");
```

Or else use single-quotes, which are typically interchangeable in HTML:

```
fwrite ($fp, "<rss version='2.0' xmlns:atom='http://www.mexautos.com/mexautosrss.xml'><channel>\n");
```

See specification of quote types to delimit HTML/SGML attributes here:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2

> By default, SGML requires that all
>   attribute values be delimited using
>   either double quotation marks (ASCII
>   decimal 34) or single quotation marks
>   (ASCII decimal 39). Single quote marks
>   can be included within the attribute
>   value when the value is delimited by
>   double quote marks, and vice versa.

The last sentence applies to HTML attribute strings that contain quotes, which is not your scenario.  But you do have PHP code with a quoted string containing quotes, and PHP supports the same policy about quotes.

Comment: Actually this is XML, not HTML/SGML, but the same applies: XML allows either kind of quote marks to delimit attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to correctly escape strings:

```
fwrite ($fp, "<rss version='2.0' xmlns:atom=\"http://www.mexautos.com/mexautosrss.xml\"><channel>\n");
```